# Keras google cloudml sample: Prediction failed

Tags: keras, google-cloud-ml-engine

I'm trying the keras cloudml sample (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census/keras) and after a bug fix ([Keras google cloudml sample: IndexError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46379932/keras-google-cloudml-sample-indexerror)) the cloud training works and I can successfully create a model, but I still cannot get the cloud predictions to work.

I've looked for a solution on stackexchange, google and read https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/troubleshooting

See below for environment, model, predict call and error.

I'm a still a noob, so it might well be I'm erring in some naive way.

Any help is appreciated,

yarc68000

------------ model ---------------

```
$ gcloud ml-engine models list
NAME                            DEFAULT_VERSION_NAME
j171011_census1_model         v1
```

------------predict and error --------------

```
$ gcloud ml-engine predict --model j171011_census1_model --version v1 --json-instances ../test.json
{
  "error": "Prediction failed: Expected tensor name: input, got tensor name: [u'hours_per_week', u'native_country', u'relationship', u'gender', u'age', u'marital_status', u'race', u'education_num', u'workclass', u'capital_loss', u'education', u'capital_gain', u'occupation']."
}
```

----------- environment ----------------

```
(env1) $ python --version
Python 2.7.13 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
(env1) $ conda list | grep 'h5py\|keras\|pandas\|numexpr\|tensorflow'
h5py                      2.7.1                    py27_1    conda-forge
keras                     2.0.6                    py27_0    conda-forge
numexpr                   2.6.2                    py27_1    conda-forge
pandas                    0.20.3                   py27_0    anaconda
tensorflow                1.3.0                     <pip>
tensorflow-tensorboard    0.1.6                     <pip>
```

Comment: Have you modified the code in any way? I just ran `git pull`, then copied and pasted all the commands out of the README.md and things worked as expected (NB: I trained locally and then deployed to the cloud). You may find it helpful to run [local prediction](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census/keras#prediction-using-gcloud-local) first

Comment: If you have modified the code, please provide information about what changes were made. If you have not, then we'll have to figure out why it works in some cases and not others.

Comment: No modifications. But I had omitted the `python preprocess.py sample.json`. My apologies. It works now. And thanks for the prompt responses.

Comment: I suggest you self-answer the question for future posterity :)